# Youtubeplayer api for Android is not showing video advertisements

Tags: java, android, video, android-youtube-api

We have developed an Application using youtubeplayer... The code is very simple and based on samples provided by youtubeplayer api...

Following is the code...

```
  
public class YouTubeVideoActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener
{

    private static int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    String strVideo_Id="";
    YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    YouTubePlayerView   youTubeView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
        /*this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = this.getWindow().getAttributes();
        layoutParams.y = 80; // top margin
        this.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
        wlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        window.setAttributes(wlp);*/


        strVideo_Id = getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_ID");
        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        int ACTIONBAR_HEIGHT = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("ACTIONBAR_HEIGHT"))-5;


        YouTubePlayerView.LayoutParams params = (YouTubePlayerView.LayoutParams)youTubeView.getLayoutParams();
        ((MarginLayoutParams) params).setMargins(0, ACTIONBAR_HEIGHT, 0, 0); 

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point p = new Point();
        int iPicHeight ;
        int iWindowWidth ;
        int iWindowHeight;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        {
            display.getRealSize(p);
            iWindowWidth = p.x;
            iWindowHeight = p.y;
        }
        else
        {
            iWindowWidth = display.getWidth();
            iWindowHeight =display.getHeight();
        }

        params.height = (int) (iWindowHeight * 0.30);


        youTubeView.setLayoutParams(params);
        youTubeView.initialize(Constants.YT_KEY, this);
        if(GenericOnTouchListner.mediaPlayer!=null && GenericOnTouchListner.mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 2;
        else
            RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    }

    public static void setMargins (View v, int l, int t, int r, int b) 
    {
        if (v.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) 
        {
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            p.setMargins(l, t, r, b);
            v.requestLayout();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) 
    {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) 
        {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        }
        else 
        {
            String errorMessage = String.format("There was an error initializing the YouTubePlayer (%1$s)", errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) 
        {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Constants.YT_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
    //  youTubeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(youTubePlayer != null)
            youTubePlayer.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        youTubeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if(youTubePlayer!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //youTubePlayer.play();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        super.onPause();
        youTubeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        /*if(youTubePlayer!=null)
            youTubePlayer.pause();*/
    }


    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider()
    {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,boolean wasRestored) 
    {
        youTubePlayer = player;
        youTubePlayer.setManageAudioFocus(true);
        youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(true);

        player.setFullscreen(true);

        youTubePlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI |
                YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE); 
        PlayerStyle style = PlayerStyle.DEFAULT;
        player.setPlayerStyle(style);
        if (!wasRestored) 
        {
            if(strVideo_Id != null)
            {
                Constants.bFromYouTube = true;
                //player.cueVideo(strVideo_Id);
                player.loadVideo(strVideo_Id);
                player.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
            }
        }
        youTubePlayer.play();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(youTubePlayer != null)
        {
            youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(false);
            Intent i = new Intent();
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

I am not doing anything specific for stopping video advertisements... But, when we load the specific video, the video advertisements are not shown...

Any inputs are welcome...

Answer (score 0):

This is because video advertisements are **served on a per-video basis**, and both the *frequency* and the *advertisement type* are decided by YouTube.

I've noticed that there are two types of advertisement: one is **pre-roll videos** and one is **slide-in banners**.

Typically, the second type of advertisement appears quite often, regardless of the orientation and/or the YouTube player style.

On the other hand, pre-roll videos are more difficult to come by. They are usually served when watching famous videos, and the orientation/the YouTube player style do make a difference. For instance, if you choose the `PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS` style, pre-roll videos are typically **not served**.

If you want to test pre-roll videos, try playing the top music videos of the moment.

Comment: You are right, but the pre-roll videos are also not playing in Android... They do show up if same url is used on browser... Player style is set to default...

Comment: Again, this is up to YouTube to decide. Pre-roll frequencies are different from browser ones, and so is the type of pre-roll. There is no way for you to "control" this behavior.

Comment: I have got clarification from one of the Youtube contact that the advt only shows up if the application is hosted on playstore...

Comment: Not in my experience. I was able to see advertising even in my simple test application.

Comment: I am not doubting that, but well, those videos that I saw were advertisements for sure :) I can either post the demo code and/or record a video of that. Ads are pretty frequent, so it won't take long for them to show up.